# How can I get a list of CACHED processes?

Tags: android, process

I am trying to get a list of cached processes. I already know how to get running processes and services by their class name, but how can I get a list of the Cached processes and services by their host name?

If you go under settings on your android device, and click "apps" then choose "running" if you press the menu button you can switch between running services or cached processes. I am trying to get a list of all cached processes by their class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source code in settings of android:
http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/applications/RunningProcessesView.java
and check the various:  `mSetBackground` in `ActiveItem`
all `mSetBackground = true` are cached processes

Answer (score 0):

So I sort of got it, this is doing exactly what the settings view does.

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
                for(RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : am.getRunningAppProcesses()){

                    if(processInfo.importance == 400) {
                        temp.append(processInfo.processName);
                        temp.append("\n");
                    }
```

But its only returning the package name and not the full activity name.